# Android calendar widget looking like Google Calendar web widget

Tags: android, calendar, widget

I'm looking for a free Android widget looking and having the same feature than the web embedable google calendar widget.

I mean, displaying the whole week with day and hour grid, then a line showing the current time, and the ability to change the week displayed.

something like the timetable on this site : http://www.univ-orleans.fr/sciences-techniques/info/miage/master-1

or just like the webinterface of google agenda (unfortunately, the android widget shows only "today" schedule :/ )

What widget could you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Calendar Widget: Month+Agenda](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itbenefit.android.calendar) it requires Android version 2.2 and up

Features

• Synced with Google calendars

• Shows markers for dates with events

• Shows today's agenda

• Shows week numbers (optional)

• Opens default calendar app by taping on date

• Beautiful and clean design

Comment: it seems to only display the mounth... :/ I'd like to display only the a week timetable, no "current day" feature, just a time timetable with a line showing the current hour (see the link I added in the question)